# Is it bad to name a Python module "global" or other keyword?

Tags: python, django

I inherited some old Django code where one of the modules is named `global` (full name in `INSTALLED_APPS` being `'labweb.global'`), which holds the models and views that drive the front page and some other scattered parts of the the site.  However, `global` is a Python keyword, so this smells...but it works.

I'm ~99% sure that it's a bad idea to name modules after keywords, but I'm somewhat amazed that it works at all.  How does Django not seem to care?

Comment: I'm just curious. How do you import it? `from labweb.global import *`?  I think you're right that `global` is definitely not okay as a module name in Python. It forces you to do awkward things to keep it from conflicting with the keyword.

Comment: I don't import the module directly, Django does so (magically?) after passing it as a string in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py`.  Other references to in the code are also done with strings (URL names, etc)

Comment: @ShashankGupta, no, any keyword in a dotted name is still a `SyntaxError`.  You can't import any such module directly.  But there are import tools in the standard library that can import modules via passing their names as strings.

Comment: I guess it works because django is probably dynamically loading the module.  A simple "import global" would give a syntax error.  It wouldn't affect the use of the usual keyword because it gets stored as a dict, and you can use any string there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course it's a Bad Idea.  Of course you can't import such a module directly:

```
import global # or any other keyword
```

just raises `SyntaxError` at compile-time.  But perhaps that's the point?  That is, perhaps the designer wanted to make sure the module **couldn't** be imported directly (but only via trickery).  I don't know - I'm just trying to be generous there ;-)

### Example

This is probably the easiest way to import such a module.  Here's file `global.py`:

```
print "I'm global!"
```

And then:

```
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.import_module("global")
I'm global!
<module 'global' from 'global.py'>
```

There are other ways to do it.  There's simply **no way** to import directly, though.